# Error publishing "hello world" Microsoft AL app to Dynamics 365 sandbox

Tags: dynamics-365

I'm attempting to publish the sample app from the Microsoft "Getting Started with AL" article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/devenv-get-started) to my company's D365 sandbox. I've followed the steps in the guide exactly, but get an authentication error when attempting to download the symbols needed to build and publish the project. My account has full admin privileges, so I shouldn't be getting any errors.

I've found several mentions of this error, but they all apply to building an external app with the NAV package rather than an add-on AL app, and none of the proposed solutions have worked. We have been attempting to get assistance from MS support as well, but have naturally gotten the runaround.

Exact error:

```
[2019-01-25 11:00:56.01] Using reference symbols cache path: c:\Users\tbarnett\Documents\AL\ALProject1\./.alpackages
[2019-01-25 11:00:56.01] Authenticating...
[2019-01-25 11:00:56.84] Sending request to https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v1.0/sandbox/dev/packages?publisher=Microsoft&appName=Application&versionText=13.0.0.0
[2019-01-25 11:00:56.85] Sending request to https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v1.0/sandbox/dev/packages?publisher=Microsoft&appName=System&versionText=13.0.0.0
[2019-01-25 11:01:25.08] The request for path /v1.0/sandbox/dev/packages?publisher=Microsoft&appName=Application&versionText=13.0.0.0 failed with code Unauthorized. Reason: Authorization has been denied for this request.
[2019-01-25 11:01:25.26] The request for path /v1.0/sandbox/dev/packages?publisher=Microsoft&appName=System&versionText=13.0.0.0 failed with code Unauthorized. Reason: Authorization has been denied for this request.
Microsoft (R) AL Compiler version 2.1.1.3797
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved

Compilation started for project 'ALProject1' containing '1' files at '11:1:25.270'.

c:\Users\tbarnett\Documents\AL\ALProject1\HelloWorld.al(5,45): error AL0247: The target Page "Customer List" for the extension object is not found

Compilation ended at '11:1:25.273'.

Error: The package could not be created.
Account permissions changed, now I receive the following:
New Error:
The request for path /v1.0/sandbox/dev/packages?publisher=Microsoft&appName=System&versionText=13.0.0.0 failed with code Forbidden. Reason: You do not have the following permissions on TableData NAV App: IndirectRead.
To view details about your permissions, see the Effective Permissions page. To report a problem, refer to the following server session ID: '109457'.
```

launch.json (I've tried with the commented out server URL, which is not mentioned in the guide above, un-commented, but with the same result):

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "al",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Microsoft cloud sandbox",
            //"server": "https://gryphonnetworks.crm.dynamics.com",
            "startupObjectId": 22,
            "startupObjectType": "Page"
        }
    ]
}
```

My development environment:

Visual Studio Code: Version: 1.30.2 (system setup)
Commit: 61122f88f0bf01e2ac16bdb9e1bc4571755f5bd8
Date: 2019-01-07T22:54:13.295Z
AL Language Extension: 2.1.69331
Electron: 2.0.12
Chrome: 61.0.3163.100
Node.js: 8.9.3
V8: 6.1.534.41
OS: Windows_NT x64 6.1.7601

Comment: Did you try opening Fiddler and see lower level auth errors?

Comment: Nothing revealed in Fiddler, but some changes were made to my account, and the error is now different. Edited the original issue to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Once the underlying error of not having IndirectRead permissions on the TableData NAV app was exposed, I was able to find the following GitHub article which detailed what permissions needed to be added to get the symbols downloaded and publish the app:

https://github.com/Microsoft/AL/issues/1701